# Реализация дерева вопрос-ответ

Tags: mysql, json, хранение-данных

Есть дерево вопрос-ответ. Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таких веток может быть несколько.

Где такое лучше всего хранить? БД или может быть JSON или еще что-то?

Answer (score -1):

Например в таком классическом виде

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` INTEGER,
  `is_answer` BOOLEAN,
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_quest_own_id FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
    REFERENCES questions (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: И за что минус?

Comment: За то, что совершенно не сказано, в чём плюсы и минусы этого подхода, а также какие сделаны предположения (например, почему вдруг вопросы и ответы размещены в одной таблице). И на данный момент в вопросе недостаточно деталей, чтобы дать ТСу полезный ответ, он ещё даже не определился с хранилищем.

Comment: @D-side я за хранилище и спрашиваю. Вопрос вроде конкретный.

Comment: @Tsyklop Мой ответ Вашу задачу решает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я рассматриваю разные варианты. Ваше предложение одно из. У самого такой вариант был, но решил спросить совета.